# In ASP.net MVC Models is there a way to manipulate data in the property setters?

Tags: passwords, asp.net-membership, password-encryption, federated-identity

This post is kindo of asking what I need but not very well... [How to encrypt password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888921/how-to-encrypt-password-in-asp-net-mvc)

Essentially I have a model "User"

```
Public Class User

    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property NickName As String

    Public Property EmailAddress As String

    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```

I want to be able to do something like this....

```
Public Class User

    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property NickName As String

    Public Property EmailAddress As String

    Public Property Password As String
        Get
            Return Password
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Password = DoMyHashing(value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Is there any way to do this simply?

**EDIT** : I have since started using BrockAllen.MembershipReboot which uses the federated identity system.  It's much better than membership provider in my opinion!

Comment: why don't you use the built in MembershipProviders?

Comment: They are a bit overkill for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is not something that should be taken *lightly* and even better not reinvented. *Simple* doesn't necessarily mean *secure*. So you could use the existing membership provider which already implements security for you and stores only hashed versions of passwords in the database.

And if you don't want to use the membership provider but implement password hashing yourself, here's a [`good guide`](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) you might consider going through before getting into coding.

Here's a secure way to generate password hashes:

> To Store a Password
>
> 1. Generate a long random salt using a CSPRNG.
> 2. Prepend the salt to the
>      password and hash it with a standard cryptographic hash function such
>      as SHA256.
> 3. Save both the salt and the hash in the user's database
>      record.
>
> To Validate a Password
>
> 1. Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
> 2. Prepend the salt
>      to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
> 3. Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the
>      database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the
>      password is incorrect.

Comment: I already know how to use password hashing and am in fact using PWDTK library for that purpose... this answer shows that you have obviously not understood my question.  What I am asking is how to automatically make changes to a given value prior to that value being stored in the database using the model getters and setters.  I have done this before in ASP.Net WebForms where I was using datarows.. in that instance I simply changed the Password_set setter to apply the hashing before inserting the new value into the datarow ... the Password_get simply returns the hashed password.

Comment: You'd better implement this functionality in your service layer, and not on your view models. Your view models should be simple POCO objects and not responsible for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Agreed. Keep your models/entities as POCO. You could always use an Action Filter on the user registration which does any sort of hashing of the users posted data, or more preferably put this in the service layer like Darin suggests.

Comment: accepted as correct answer.  I ended up going with VS2012 MVC4 and the Simple Membership Provider it ships with (didn't know this existed til I got VS2012) .. thanks for the help :)